# Searching for occurrence of a string using c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, string, stl, substring

I need to find an occurrence of string in an string. Is there any find function in c++? For example, if I have a string `example/example/example/a/a`, how to get a number of occurrences of string `example`, which in this case is 3?

Comment: Accept some answers for your previous questions.

Comment: Does "eee" match "eeee" once or twice?

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment?

Comment: so no one will help for that???

Comment: @ZacHowland: Yes, it does.  No one but students ever need to search for a substring.

Comment: @Fred:  It was the wording of the question that made me think so, hence the reason for the question mark at the end of my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the substring function.

```
  std::string to_search = "example/example/example/a/a";
  std::string to_find = "example";

  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < to_search.length() - to_find.length(); i++) {
    if (to_search.substr(i, to_find.length()) == to_find)
      count++;
  }
```

Comment: Consider using `std::equal` instead to avoid creating lots of temporary strings.  (That still wouldn't be optimal, but it would be better)

Comment: Very inefficient way of searching for substring. Hint: you can skip more than one character at a time.

Comment: This wasn't supposed to be efficient. I just provided a simple solution for a simple question. Of course there are better solutions with iterators.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is a function the **finds** content in a string. ;-)

You can **find** this and more by looking at `std::string` API:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

Comment: `h=example/example/example/a/a;int c=0;
 while(h.find("example")!=NULL)
 {

  c=c+1;  cout<<c<<endl;
 }`
this fails may i know y???

Comment: Everytime you do find it starts from the beginning of the string h, also it returns the position of the string or npos if it is not found and not a pointer, so a NULL comparison is not correct.  There is an optional parameter pos that determines the starting position to search from and since the query returns the position of the previously found search, just do find until it returns npos.